# Import PHP library into Cassandra - Faker

Tags: php, cassandra, nosql

i want to import the Faker PHP Test Data (https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#installation) into Cassandra.

Where do i start or where can i find some support for this? 
I'm pretty new to this field and just want to play with this data because i'm currently reading the Book "Build API'S you want hate"

Thanks for your advice & best regards,

florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [DataStax PHP Driver for Apache Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver). Using this driver (or any of the [other](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/drivers.html?highlight=drivers#php) community drivers) you should be able to create your keyspace(s) and table(s) while using Faker to generate data that you can then insert into Cassandra.